# Perspective confusion in Sky Map mobile app

Tags: optics, astronomy

I have recently ran into an observation which broke my mental schemes, using the [Sky Map](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.stardroid&hl=es) mobile application.

For an introduction before my actual issue, I should state my understanding that, since the Sun is so far away from us, then all rays casted along any huge area (not involving an actual significant Earth angular change) are almost parallel. Similarly, if looking at the Sun from any point of such area keeping the same head/body rotation, then it should appear basically at the same relative position in our eyes's field of view. Right?

Now, using this [Sky Map](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.stardroid&hl=es) app, I had the idea to move the mobile around while keeping its rotation unchanged, and it turns out that the displayed sky scene drastically shifts, literally inducing important eye angle changes for any stars / objets of reference to look at between the initial and final physical body positions. But this shouldn't make any sense, since these objects appear in reality in the same direction when moving ourselves around without changing angles, like the exposed concept on first paragraph.

How is this even possible?

Comment: it might be possible that there is a bug in the app wrt the GPS calculation or any sensor is faulty in your phone. After all, the app is trying to mimic nature, it is very natural to run into such problems which will help us improve it further!!

Comment: I understand then this is a bug or a phone issue as well. Using Redmi 7. I just need to make sure I'm not being tricked by any perception misunderstanding, as a non-physicist person.